# Possible file missing for Google .net API

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

When I try to call .Execute() on a request I'm asked to locate ClientServiceRequest.cs on my computer. I assumed this would be included in the NuGet package but it isn't and I can't find anything on how or where I should get it or what it IS included in. Has anyone experienced anything like this before?

Elaboration is needed-

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var ics = new BaseClientService.Initializer
   {
       ApplicationName = "appname",
       ApiKey = "[APIkey]",
   } as IClientService;
   var inst = new InstancesResource.GetRequest(ics, "project-name",
       "zone", "exampleinstance");
   var instresponse = inst.Execute();          //Error is on this line
   instresponse.Name = "geninstance";
   var instinsert = new InstancesResource.InsertRequest(ics, 
       instresponse, "projectname", "zone");
   instinsert.Execute();
}
```

The first time I run this code it gives me a window to browse my computer and wants me to find *"ClientServiceRequest.cs"*, I've searched for it and it wasn't found so I click cancel on the browse window and then it throws a NullReferenceException on the line mentioned above and just throws the exception every time I run the code after that.

Please tell me if my code is stupid, it's very likely as I got this error when I was about to try and test it.

Comment: which nugget package did grab?

Comment: I installed "Google.Apis" and "Google.Apis.Compute.v1" the problem comes when I try to execute an InstanceResources.GetRequest

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: Can you post the exact error you are getting? The source code is available by the way here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis/Apis/Requests/ClientServiceRequest.cs?name=1.8.2

Comment: I just edited the question to give more information. If I do have to download any of the source, do you where would be the most sensible place to put it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look in our OAuth 2.0 page - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth, and the authorization part in https://developers.google.com/+/api/. You will have to use the authorization mechanism.

Comment: I am guessing that Visual Studio, while running your program in Debug mode, wants access to the Google API source code. Try checking the checkbox for "Just My Code" in Visual Studio / Tools / Options / Debugging / General.

Comment: @peleyal will that fix the error I'm getting?

Comment: Also if the application is only intended to manage instances on one specific project but from multiple locations are you sure I need OAuth2? I was under the impression that OAuth2 is only needed if you're managing/accessing someone else's project/information

Comment: thanks! do you know if there's a way to enter my own credentials in OAuth 2.0 programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to peleyal for the help, question is pretty much answered, the code needs OAuth 2.0 and I had to download the source for the .net api. For the record-

```
var ics = new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    ApplicationName = "appname",
    ApiKey = "[APIkey]",
} as IClientService;
```

isn't a stroke of genius and probably doesn't even work. It's much more sensible to use-

```
var cs = new ComputeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        ApplicationName = "appname",
        ApiKey = "[APIKEY]",
    });
```

like a normal human and that works whereever ics is used in the question's code.

Thanks everyone!